# XML return from WCF application

Tags: .net, wcf

I am using WCF to get data from database from my web application using .net framework. In my WCF application code, requirement is to get data in XML format. In my web application code, requirement is to call WCF service using object to get data of database in XML format.

WCF service.cs code is as follows

```
public class AWS_WCF_Service : IAWS_WCF_Service
{
    public SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection();

    public SqlConnectionStringBuilder Sbu = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    public static SqlConnection GlobalConnection_Web = new SqlConnection();

    public SqlConnectionStringBuilder Sbu_Web = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public static DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();


    public void DoWork()
    {

    }


    public XmlDocument RetrieveData(String Tblname, String StationID, DateTime date)
    {
        bool flgPrcs = OpenDB();

        if (flgPrcs == false)
        {
            return null;
        }

        String Query = "select * from " + Tblname + " where ID = ' 1 ' "

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, Con);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
        string xmlStr = "";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xmlStr = myDataSet.GetXml();

        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

        return xmlDoc;
    }

    public bool OpenDB()
    {
        if (Con.State.ToString().ToUpper() == "OPEN")
        {
            Con.Close();
        }

        Sbu.DataSource = @"XXXXXXX";
        Sbu.InitialCatalog = "XXXXX";
        Sbu.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        Sbu.UserID = "XXXX";
        Sbu.Password = "XXXXX";

        Con.ConnectionString = Sbu.ConnectionString;
        Con.Open();

        return true;
    }

    public bool CloseDB()
    {
        if (Con.State.ToString().ToUpper() == "OPEN")
        {
            Con.Close();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

WCF interface code is as follows

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAWS_WCF_Service
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract,XmlSerializerFormat]
    System.Xml.XmlDocument RetrieveData(String Tblname, String StationID, DateTime  date);

    [OperationContract]
    bool OpenDB();

    [OperationContract]
    bool CloseDB();

}
```

Web application from where i use WCF to get data into XML , code is as follows

```
 AWS_Service1.AWS_WCF_ServiceClient ObjAwsSer = new AWS_WCF_ServiceClient();

 XmlDocument OBJXml = ObjAwsSer.RetrieveData("XXX", "XX", DateTime.Now);
```

Here I am getting following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'

Comment: I would assume that the exception has nothing to do with WCF. Can you perhaps set a breakpoint in the service code?

Comment: you are returning `XmlElement` inplace of `XmlDocument`. Please check or show the code for the contract `RetrieveData`.

Comment: Can you not return String which is xml rather than a XmlDocument so that the service becomes more interoperable.

Comment: saravanan -> i am returning XMLDocument itselt not XMLElement, in "RetrieveData" function. "RetrieveData" function code is mentioned in my post.

Comment: Rajesh -> Yes i can return String but my requirement is to get XML object.